# Extract Substring in Comma Separated values in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.1

Two Variables in Postgresql:

```
V_VAR :='US185268001,US285268002,US385268005'; --Input
V_OUT := '001,002,005'; --Expected output to be stored
```

Any idea how to do in postgresql? Last 3 characters of each comma separated value. How to manipulate the V_VAR variable to get the output as V_OUT variable.

Update:

Please Note: V_VAR can have any number of CSV list. Here i have 3 values for the example purpose.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Is there always just three values in the CSV list?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. No, it can be any number of CSV list.

Comment: Now I guess you see the problem with putting CSV lists in a column :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using a regex replacement here:

```
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '.*?([0-9]{3})(,|$)', '\1\2', 'g') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

The strategy here is to match lazily until matching (and capturing) the final 3 digits of each code in one group, and an optional comma in a second group.  Then, we replace with just the three digits and optional comma separator.

Note: As @BillKarvin has pointed out, storing unnormalized CSV is not optimal database design.  Please consider getting each code onto a separate record if possible.

Comment: I was thinking of splitting to a table then aggregation, but a regex is much more straight-forward.

Comment: We have proper design. Actually i am getting this data in a XML tag. Previously i was getting only single value and now it is changed with multi values. So i need to manipulate the data to get the required output. My Where condition had equal (=) symbol, after this change i will change it to IN operator. @BillKarwin

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thanks for your answer. I tried with it and it gives the output like (First value got last 3 digits and no change in next 2 values.

Comment: @Karthik My original answer was for Oracle (you tagged with many different databases).  I have updated for Postgres, in which case you need to add a global flag to `REGEXP_REPLACE`.